# Remote hotplug Python debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, uwsgi

How I can setup a hotpluggable remote debugger with Python IDE integration? For example using PyCharm. By hotpluggable I mean: can connect and disconnect from dev server on fly.

I have dev server in the cloud (django, nginx, uwsgi, postgres, debian), and use PyCharm as the main IDE (but if you have solution for any other IDE, please provide it).

Sometimes, I need to connect and debug scripts without stopping/restarting the dev server. Using PyCharm's debugger (pydevd), dev server cannot start without working debugger server (`Connection refused`), and if I stop the remote debugger while the dev server is running, it crashes e.g.

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I found pdg/epdg but they have no integration with PyCharm. Also PyCharm has a nice feature : "Attach to process", but it works only with local processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach that would probably work is to set up a signal handler to the program you want to debug to load in a debugger. Then sending the process a signal to debug (via the `kill` command) you could then attach remotely.

Here is how you'd do this via the [python trepan](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan2) [debuggers](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k)

```
import signal

def signal_handler(num, f):
    from trepan.interfaces import server as Mserver
    from trepan.api import debug
    connection_opts={'IO': 'TCP', 'PORT': 1955}
    intf = Mserver.ServerInterface(connection_opts=connection_opts)
    dbg_opts = {'interface': intf}
    print('Starting TCP server listening on port 1955.')
    debug(dbg_opts=dbg_opts)
    return

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)
# Go about your business...

import time
import os
print(os.getpid())
for i in range(10000):
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Now run that:

```
$ python /tmp/foo.py
8530
```

From above output we helpfully listed the pid of the Python process we want to debug.

Now in a shell we send a signal to tell the process to go into the debugger that is set up in the signal handler. You will have to adjust the
process id.

```
$ kill -USR1 8530   # Adjust the pid to what you see above
```

And in the shell where we ran `/tmp/foo.py` you should now see
the new output:

```
$ python /tmp/foo.py
8530
Starting TCP server listening on port 1955. # This is new
```

Back to the shell where we issued the `kill -USR1`, we now attach the the process now stopped inside a debugger:

```
$ trepan2 --client --port 1955
Connected.
(/tmp/foo.py:11 @101): signal_handler
-- 11     return
(trepan2*) list
  6         connection_opts={'IO': 'TCP', 'PORT': 1955}
  7         intf = Mserver.ServerInterface(connection_opts=connection_opts)
  8         dbg_opts = {'interface': intf}
  9         print('Starting TCP server listening on port 1955.')
 10         debug(dbg_opts=dbg_opts)
 11  ->     return
 12
 13     signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, signal_handler)
 14     # Go about your business...
 (trepan2*) backtrace
 ->   0 signal_handler(num=10, f=<frame object at 0x7f9036796050>)
      called from file '/tmp/foo.py' at line 11
 ##   1 <module> file '/tmp/foo.py' at line 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!