# (How) can I use pydevd on the command line similar to pdb?

Tags: python, pydev, pdb

I know that I can debug `Dummy.py` on the command line like this:

```
python -m pdb Dummy.py
```

Now, I am trying to understand some behavior of the debug console in Visual Studio Code which I believe I might track down to behavior of `pydevd`. (Basically, the debug console [reports incorrect error messages](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2949) for lines such as `a = no_existing_function()`.)

So what I would like to do is use `pydevd` in a similar way to `pdb` above, but I fail to achieve that. I have already managed to start a "server",

```
import pydevconsole
pydevconsole.start_server('localhost', 5678, 1234)
```

and start a "client" and connect to the above server:

```
import pydevd
from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_comm

print(pydevd_comm.start_client('localhost', 5678))
pydevd.settrace()
```

However, I am unsure what to do next. It seems to me like `pydevd` is only an intermediary expecting something else to connect to the port which I have chosen to be `1234`. But what is it actually expecting there? Can I connect with something like telnet, or short-circuit this connect altogether to get a truely interactive console where I can type commands to be evaluated in the scope of `Dummy.py`?

Comment: Possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169047/no-pydevd-protocol-specification

Comment: Two more related things to collect here: `set PYDEV_DEBUG=True` to enable more debug output in `pydevd`, and https://github.com/nyyManni/pydev-client

Answer (score 1):

If you're using visual studio code, you want to use `ptvsd` instead of `pydevd` (`ptvsd` wraps `pydevd` to use with visual studio code).

See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging for details (you have to start the remote debugger and then connect to it with a launch configuration).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The reason this does not help me is when I notice a bug in VS Code, it is almost impossible to attribute it to VS Code, the PVSC extension, the PTVSD wrapper of the debugging engine, or the PyDev debugging egine. If I were able to repro a bug in PyDev, I would be certain where to turn to to investigate and/or report the bug.

Comment: If you have a bug in the debugger when using vscode, you should report to `ptvsd` (https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/) -- if it's not from there it should be redirected as appropriate.